# Async-Await in a for-loop while getting data using cheerio.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, cheerio

I am trying to get data using [Cheerio.js](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), and using async/await to synchronize requests.

Here is my (pseudo)code:

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){

rp(url)
    .then(async (html) => {
        const $ = await cheerio.load(html);
        dataItem1 = await $('input[id=data1]').val();
        console.log(dataItem1);
        await console.log("yay!" + i);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

When I run it using node.js, I get the output as:

```
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 4
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 4
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 4
```

but what I want is

```
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 1
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 2
<required dataItem1>
Yay! 3
```

Where am I going wrong, and what changes should I make in the code to get the desired output?

Comment: Don't use `var`, especially in loops, especially when there's anything asynchronous involved - use `let` instead (and `const` whenever the variable isn't going to be reassigned)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! by changing it to `let`, now I don't get the order as `4,4,4`, but with 1s, 2s and 3s only. But it isn't in the order as `1,2,3`. When I run the script repeatedly, I am getting it sometimes as `3,2,1` , `2,3,1` , `3,1,2` etc.

Comment: If you need it to be in order, `await` each Promise in the loop

Comment: eg `await rp(url)...`

Comment: @CertainPerformance By adding `await` before `rp(url)`, it gives the error as `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

Comment: Sounds like the containing function isn't `async`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot @CertainPerformance it worked! I was stuck on this problem for quite a lot of time...